# Increasing in slope result in increasing in impedance of BJT Early voltage?

Tags: bjt

I'm studying about the AC equivalent model of BJT and in the r<sub>e</sub> model, it said that:

"As the base current increases the slope of the line increases, resulting in an increase in output impedance with increase in base and collector current"

[image: Characteristic curve]

I thought that the impedance is equal to the r<sub>o</sub> in the denominator, so base on the formula of the slope in the picture then if the slope increases, the value of r<sub>o</sub> decreases and therefore the impedance should decrease rather than increase.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The "steeper" the slope is the lower the ro resistance is. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV6wP.png

Comment: Where did you read such surprising "explanations"? I suppose - any obscure internet source?

Comment: Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory (11th Edition) by Robert L. Boylestad, Louis Nashelsky - page 259.  That's why I felt so confused because it's in a textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"As the base current increases the slope of the line increases,
>   resulting in an increase in output impedance with increase in base and
>   collector current"*

They got it wrong - as the slope increases you get more amps per volt so conductance increases and conductance is the inverse of resistance.

Comment: Yes....the quoted text is without sense...: "As the base current increases......resulting in an increase in.....base ...current." Crazy!